# Can I simply install a fresh OS X without a thumb drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, install

I've always installed a new OS X install via a thumb drive. However, at that time, I only had a single hard drive. Now, I have two hard drives, but the question is: Do I still need a thumb drive now?

I would say I simply copy my main installation to my second hard drive (Carbon Copy Cloner?) and then format the main drive and simply run the installer, stored on the second drive and install OS X on the first drive. No need for a thumb drive, right?

Comment: I'll edit out the Yosemite to see if it stands alone as you mentioned - could you explain a bit why you always needed a thumb drive? I've never needed a thumb drive to install OS X although I know it's a popular thing for people to ask about. Detailing why might help us link this to an existing question or know if it's a new one for the site.

Comment: Well, one thing for sure; there goes the view count, by removing out the currently trendy 'yosemite' search. ;) - In reply to your question, I just typed quite a lot, but then I thought that a thumb drive is in fact unnecessary, even with just a single drive, as long as you have two partitions.. Though, I got to admit I just thought of that.. Surprisingly stupid. In fact, I always knew that, but never realized it would've been so easy.

Comment: I ask "dumb" questions all the time. Also, we will likely have a nice discussion on [meta] about whether to change the policy to not have pre-release software if Apple keeps opening up the NDA and seeding / encouraging public discussion.

Comment: Look at Answer :D :D

Comment: recovery mode  tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be possible. At least it was possible for previous OS X's, but I don't see why they changed it. So **yes**, you can run the installer from the second hard drive onto the first one. You can even install any other OS X onto another partition on the same hard drive.